# Why does Trackpy give me an error when I try to compute the overall drift speed?

Tags: trackpy

I'm going through the Trackpy walkthrough (http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.3.0/tutorial/walkthrough.html) but using my own pictures. When I get to calculating the overall drift velocity, I get this error and I don't know what it means:[drift error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfez4.png)

I don't have a ton of coding experience so I'm not even sure how to look at the source code to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried or errors you have encountered. Also add more tags so the question is visible to a larger audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the traceback of the error, i.e. you called a function, `tp.compute_drift()`, but this function called another function, `pandas_sort()`, which called another function, etc until `raise ValueError(msg)` is called, which interrupts the chain. The last line is the actual error message:

```
ValueError: 'frame' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.
```

To understand it, you have to know that Trackpy stores data in `DataFrame` objects from the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library. The tracking data you want to extract drift motion from is stored in such an object, `t2`. If you print `t2` it will probably look like this:

```
                 y            x      mass  ...        ep  frame  particle
frame                                      ...                           
0        46.695711  3043.562648  3.881068  ...  0.007859      0         0
3979   3041.628299  1460.402493  1.787834  ...  0.037744      0         1
3978   3041.344043  4041.002275  4.609833  ...  0.010825      0         2
```

The word "frame" is the title of two columns, which confuses the sorting algorithm. As the error message says, it is ambiguous to sort the table by frame.

**Solution**

The index (leftmost) column does not need a name here, so remove it with

```
t2.index.name = None
```

and try again. Check if you have the newest Trackpy and Pandas versions.